# How can I update a struct, setting most but not all of the fields to a default value?

Tags: rust

I know about the great Rust feature:

```
Foo {
    fieldX: someValue,
    ..Self::default()
}
```

I want to use this in a method with `&mut self`, not touching fields `f10` and `f11` and setting the others to default:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo {
    f1: u32,
    //...
    f10: Vec<u32>,
    f11: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn f1(&mut self) {
        let new_me = Foo {
            f10: self.f10,
            ..Self::default()
        };
        *self = new_me;
    }
}
```

but the compiler says:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:12:18
   |
12 |             f10: self.f10,
   |                  ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How can I:

1. Leave signature of `f1` as is: `&mut self`
2. Not copy any `Vec<>`, only moving
3. Not write boring code, like

   ```
   self.f1 = 0;
   self.f2 = 0;
   self.f3 = None;
   // ...
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd replace the entire `self` with the default value, then preserve the interesting fields from the previous value:

```
use std::mem;

impl Foo {
    fn f1(&mut self) {
        let old = mem::replace(self, Self::default());
        self.f10 = old.f10;
    }
}
```